# ASP.Net MVC checkbox values from view to custom controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a table that displays my model items. I've extracted the relevant portions of my view:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Provision>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAndSend", "Provision", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model != null && Model.Any())
    {
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
                ...
                // other column headers
                ...
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IncludeProvision)
                </th>
                ...
                // other column headers
                ...
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    ...
                    // other columns
                    ...
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IncludeProvision)
                    </td>
                    ...
                    // other columns
                    ...
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <button id="save" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save + Send</button>
    }
    ...
}
```

This works fine and the checkbox values are displayed correctly in the view depending on the boolean value of the `IncludeProvision` field for the given model item.

As per Andrew Orlov's answer, I've modified the view and controller and the `SaveAndSend()` controller method is now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAndSend(List<Provision> provisions)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // perform all the save and send functions
        _provisionHelper.SaveAndSend(provisions);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

However, at this point the passed in model object is null.

Including the Provision model object for completeness:

```
namespace
{
    public partial class Provision
    {
        ...
        // other fields
        ...
        public bool IncludeProvision { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to grab the checked/unchecked value from each checkbox and update the session `IncludeProvision` field for each model item when the 'SaveAndSend' button is clicked?

Comment: You should just have a `HttpPost` method and not a JavaScript redirect, then submit your model and you can then put your data in the session and do the redirect.

Comment: Try to avoid of checking model for null on view. It is controller job in your case.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov hmm I was just following ReSharper's suggested code refactor on this one, assuming it's not completely optimized to follow MVC best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for properties in a collection. It creates duplicate `name` attributes (in your case `name="item.IncludeProvision"`) which have no relationship to your model and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Use either a `for` loop (you models needs to be `IList<Provision>`

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IncludeProvision)<td>
  </tr>
}
```

or create an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Provision`. In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Provision.cshtml` (note the name of the template must match the name of the type)

```
@model Provision
<tr>
  <td>....</td>
  <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IncludeProvision)<td>
</tr>
```

and in the main view (the model can be `IEnumerable<Provision>`)

```
<table>
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mattytommo said in comments, you should post your model to controller. It can be done with putting your checkbox inside a form. After clicking on button "Save and exit" all data from inputs inside this form will be serialized and sent to your controller where you can perform manipulations with session variables and so on. After that you can redirect wherever you like.

**Model**

```
public class YourModel
{
    ...
    public bool IncludeProvision { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
@model YourModel

...
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAndSend", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludeProvision)
    ...
    <button type="submit">Save and send</button>
}
...
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAndSend(YourModel model)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             // Some magic with your data
             return RedirectToAction(...);
         }

         return View(model); // As an example
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm my model in the view is of type `List<Provision>`, rather than `Provision`. Wrapping the table in a form with an `HttpPost` to my controller method with the following signature results in a null `provisions` object.


`public ActionResult SaveAndSend(List<Provision> provisions)`

Comment: How did you generate your table ? Parse your model.List<Provision> with a foreach to create each <tr><td> and when you submit post, you will retrieve the model

Comment: Well, we've should see your view and model for more accurate answer.

Comment: @User.Anonymous That's exactly how I generated my table.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov updated my question with snippets of view, controller method and model code. Thanks for your help

Comment: @illya In your case it should be better to create EditorTemplate or DisplayTemplate. So you can avoid of using `foreach`. So your model should be serialized correctly.